Error in Hardhat Deployment Script: 'upload.deployed is not a function'
I'm working on deploying a smart contract using Hardhat, but I'm encountering an error that says 'upload.deployed is not a function'. Below is the code I am using:
javascript
Copy code
    // Importing the Hardhat runtime environment
    const hre = require("hardhat");

    async function main() {
        // Fetching the contract factory for the "Upload" contract
        const Upload = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Upload");
        // Deploying the contract
        const upload = await Upload.deploy();

        // Awaiting the completion of the deployment
        await upload.deployed();

        // Output the address to which the contract was deployed
        console.log("Library deployed to:", upload.address);
    }

    // Handling errors and setting an appropriate exit code
    main().catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exitCode = 1;
});

In this script, I first obtain a contract factory for a contract named Upload. I then deploy this contract and wait for the deployment to complete. Finally, I log the address of the deployed contract. However, the

replace await upload.deployed(); to upload.waitForDeployment();
and then
replace upload.address to await upload.getAddress()
and then run again
